# Save an image from instagram through the "web developer tools" of a browser (chromium)

Tags: google-chrome, images, download, webpage

I'd like to get (and save, i.e., download) an image from an instagram web page.

I understand that I could use the "inspect this element" menu in Chromium browser to get to the "Web Developer tools", and find the image resource there.

Where exactly should I go in the web developer tools to get the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invoke the "web developer tools" in Chromium through the "inspect element" menu.

Then look in the "Resources" tab, open the "Frames" list on the left, then open the "Images" sublist of the "Frames" list, then find the image you are interested in in the list of images.

There you can get the URL for opening or downloading it by right-clicking the image and using the "Copy image URL" menu item (for example).